# Как изменить имя ключа базы данных firebase

Tags: android, база-данных, firebase

Нужно записывать данные в firebase database. Использую код из документации

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("*****");

    myRef.push().setValue(*****);
```

Так я задаю значение ключу, а как задать название? По умолчанию используется рандом, насколько я понял. Какой оператор выполняет такую функцию?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оператор push() используется дл того, чтобы система сама генерировала случайный ID

```
// Генерируем референс для нового места и добавления данных
DatabaseReference pushedPostRef = postsRef.push();

// Получаем уникальный айди сгенерированный методом push()
String postId = pushedPostRef.getKey();
```

Для того, чтобы складывать в БД свои собственные ключи, отправляйте примерно так:

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
databaseReference.child("users_models").child("my_user_1").setValue(userModel);
```

При отсутствии в БД такого ключа, система сама создаст первую запись.